# Compute the surface integral

Tags: calculus, surface-integrals

I want to compute the surface integral $\int_SF\cdot n \ dS$ with $F(x,y,z)=(x^2+\sin y^2, y^2+\sin z^2, z+\sin (xy))$ and $S$ the surface of the bounded solid that is defined by the surfaces $z=x^2+y^2+1$ and $z=2(x^2+y^2)$ with orientation of the normal to the outside of the solid.

$$$$

We have to compute the surface integral over $S_1:z=x^2+y^2+1$ and $S_2:z=2(x^2+y^2)$ and then we have to add the result, or not?

We have to find the unit normal vector and compute then the dot product with the function $F$, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not use stoke's theorem.  The contour that is formed by the two surfaces is a circle ($x^2+y^2=1$ with radius 1 and thus $r = <cost, sint,2>$.  Find r'(t) and then get the dot. product of F and r'(t) and then over $2\pi$ evaluate  the line integral $\int F.dr$  that will give you the surface integral.  But your F looks pretty ugly and it requires a lot of trignometric multiplication and integration.

Comment: So, we compute $F(r(t))\cdot r'(t)$ and then compute the integral $\int_0^{2\pi}F(r(t))\cdot r'(t)dt$, right?

Comment: You are correct. That is the beauty of stoke's theorem, equivalence of line integral and surface integral

Comment: I see!! Thank you!! :-)

Comment: @SatishRamanathan Excuse me sir, for this question, shouldn't we firstly  find the vector field, say,  $G(x,y,z)$ , such that its curl =$F(x,y,z)$, then we are able to apply Stokes theorem to $G(x,y,z)$ by $\int_0^{2\pi}G(r(t))\cdot r'(t)dt$?